Dictionary form used to talk about resulting state
In this sentence: 今日の3時までに届けてもらえるように連絡したんですけど、まだ届かないんです。The state is not yet delivered but I don't know why 届かない is used. Isn't 届いていない more appropriate here?

Related: Why is the plain negative in this sentence translated as "haven't"?

I think both sentences are appropriate, and they essentially have the same meaning. Even the neuance is quite similar:

まだ届かないんです。
まだ届いていないんです。

This is an interesting question, because in other situations, the nuance can be different. For example, if you are asked whether you have spoken with 田中さん, and you want to say you haven't:

田中さんとまだ話さないです。
田中さんとまだ話していないです。

Both sentences mean "I haven't talked to 田中さん," but the nuance is different. The first one not only means you haven't spoken to 田中さん, but it also suggests that it might be intentional, perhaps you're not ready to talk to them for some reason.
Here is another example. Imagine you have a cat who has been sick and hasn't eaten for a while. A friend asks you if your cat has eaten recently, and you answer:

まだ食べないです。
まだ食べてないです。

Both sentences mean "My cat hasn't eaten yet," but the first sentence implies that the cat might purposefully avoiding food, perhaps because it's instinctively trying to recover faster.
Now, what's the difference between these sentences? Your sentence talks about a package (荷物), while the other examples involve yourself and your cat - both of them can have a will, unlike a package.
To clarify,  let's look at the complete sentence:.

荷物はまだ届かないです。
私は田中さんとはまだ話さないです。
猫はまだ食べないです。

Since 荷物 (the package) cannot have a will, using 届かない here is fine. But when talking about a person or an animal, the sentence can imply intentionality.

Thank you for your reply. If まだ is not in the sentence, can I only use 届いていない to refer to the not yet delivered state? In my understanding, using 届かない without まだ in this situation can not convey the above meaning.

@ThuanNguyen I believe anything with まだ is "still" or "not yet"; remove まだ and you remove the nuance. If something does not have a will then it can not say either; it can only say it is or is not.

@ThuanNguyen Both  届いていない and 届かない are common phrases used to refer to the state of something not being delivered. So, removing まだ still conveys the same meaning.

@Takashi Wow this is really new to me. Thank you for helping.
